# Flask how to refresh adminer view after using _on_model_change

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

after i edit a worthy value in pic the checked value change but i must refresh the page to see this update how i make it change in view without refresh the page. and this is the function i call it in _on_model_change function.
thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSynY.png)

```
def update_checked_after_change_worthy(model):
    new_worthy = model.worthy
    old_worthy = 'No' if model.label == 0 else 'Yes'
    if new_worthy != old_worthy:
        model.checked = True
```

i expect the the checked value update without refresh the page